# Fetch info from mysql database and enter it into php url

Tags: php, mysql, json, api

I am trying to fetch a username from the database and so I can fetch the json from the person. The code I currently have gave me an error 500 and probably cause of the $json...

Can someone help me find a solution....

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.formice.com/mouse/stats.json?n= <?php echo $userRow['mouse']; ?> &l=en'); 
$obj = json_decode($json);
?>
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://api801.herokuapp.com/get/mice/<?php echo $userRow['mouse']; ?> '); 
$objj = json_decode($json);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title><?php echo $obj->name; ?> | CheeseStatz</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Favicon.ico" /> 
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<!-- ADD THE CLASS layout-top-nav TO REMOVE THE SIDEBAR. -->
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue layout-top-nav">
<div class="wrapper">

  <header class="main-header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand"><b>Cheese</b>Statz</a>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-left" id="navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.transformice.com/">Transformice</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Stats<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="mice.php">Mice Stats</a></li>
                <li><a href="race.php">Racing Stats</a></li>
                <li><a href="boot.php">Bootcamp Stats</a></li>
                <li><a href="surv.php">Survivor Stats</a></li>        
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="run4.php">Run for Cheese Stats</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="tribe.php">Your tribe Stats</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="navbar-search-input" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        <!-- Navbar Right Menu -->
        <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- Messages: style can be found in dropdown.less-->
            <li class="dropdown messages-menu">

            <!-- User Account Menu -->
            <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
              <!-- Menu Toggle Button -->
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <!-- The user image in the navbar-->
                <img src="http://outil.derpolino.shost.ca/avatar/avatar.php?p=cheesezwheel" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
                <!-- hidden-xs hides the username on small devices so only the image appears. -->
                <span class="hidden-xs"> <?php echo $obj->name; ?> </span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <!-- The user image in the menu -->
                <li class="user-header">
                  <img src="http://outil.derpolino.shost.ca/avatar/avatar.php?p=cheesezwheel" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">

                  <p>
                    <?php echo $obj->name; ?> - <?php echo $obj->title; ?>
                    <small>Level: <?php echo $objj->level; ?> </small>
                  </p>
                </li>
                <!-- Menu Body -->
                <li class="user-body">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                      <a href="blog.php">Blog</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                      <a href="help.php">Help</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                      <a href="log.php">Log</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.row -->
                </li>
                <!-- Menu Footer-->
                <li class="user-footer">
                  <div class="pull-left">
                    <a href="forum.php" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Forum</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pull-right">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-custom-menu -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Full Width Column -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
      <section class="content-header">
        <h1>
          CheeseStatz
          <small>Transformice Api v.1.0.0</small>
        </h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><?php echo $obj->name; ?></a></li>
          <li class="active">Welcome</li>
        </ol>
      </section>

      <!-- Main content -->
      <section class="content">
  <div class="callout callout-info">
                <h4>Welcome <?php echo $obj->name; ?>!</h4>

                <p></p>
          <!-- /.box-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box -->
      </section>
      <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <footer class="main-footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
        <b>Version</b> 1.0.0
      </div>
      <strong>Copyright &copy; 2015 <a href="http://transformice.com">Cheesezwheel</a>.</strong> All rights
      reserved.
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </footer>
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
<script src="../../plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- SlimScroll -->
<script src="../../plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="../../plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="../../dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="../../dist/js/demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 500 error is just a generic error. Look at the error log. Also, your script is vulnerable to SQL injection. You may want to consider using PDO or mysqli with bound parameters.

Comment: There is no error. Just a google chrome 500 error

Comment: @Cheesezwheel - look in your webserver's error log.

Comment: @Cheesezwheel The 500 error comes from your server, not Google Chrome. That's why it probably says internal server error.

Comment: There all errors about missing files( which ain't the problem)

Comment: Ik mike That's why i want to find a solution for my problems. Comes from where it says $json.

Comment: You have a syntax error. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php for understanding how strings work.

Comment: You need: `'http://api.formice.com/mouse/stats.json?n=' . $userRow['mouse'] . '&l=en'`

Comment: Just what i need, thx....

Comment: I still get a 500 error with mike answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:
     'http://api.formice.com/mouse/stats.json?n=' . $userRow['mouse'] . '&l=en'

Answer (score 0):

1. I just dont' see why you open and close your php syntax so much
2. in your link (`file_get_contents`) you could just use the variables, no need to echo them
3. check how many result you get from running that query to see if the query is correct
4. your using ' in your `file_get_comments` statement, meaning everything after is not run but just text, so it will open 
   n= php echo `$userRow['mouse']` instead of the db value of mouse like n=12